# Select random value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to do the following query? It would save me having to go out of SQL to do post-processing of the query:

```
SELECT date, RANDOM('CA', 'DE', 'AZ') FROM table LIMIT 3
```

And the result would be something like:

```
2014-01-01,"CA"
2014-01-02,"CA"
2014-01-03,"DE"
```

Is there a way to do the `RANDOM` operation in SQL?

Comment: is there is any problem if you get the info to array and take random one from this array  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your set of values to table/subquery with `UNION ALL`, sort by `RAND()` and return 1 value:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77fb8/4/0)**

```
SELECT id,
       (SELECT 'CA' AS 'col'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'DE'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT'CZ'
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS Random
FROM tab
LIMIT 3
```

Or use:

**[SqlFiddleDemo_2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ea375/2/0)**

```
SELECT id,
      ELT(FIELD(CEILING(RAND()*3), 1, 2, 3),'CA','CZ', 'DE') AS Rand
FROM tab
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: @David542 If there is a lot of values instead of UNION ALL use predefined table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('CA,DE,AZ',',',CEILING(RAND()*3)),',',-1);
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

One way is this if you want to select the random string

```
select any_column_name,ELT(FLOOR(RAND()*8)+1,'US', 'CA', 'FR', 'DE' , 'UK' , 'IR' , 
  'RU' , 'GR') from table_name;
```

Let me know if that is what you want.